# Is there any way to make JS-Beautify handle the JavaScript slash comments?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make js-beautify handle the javascript "//" comments?

Example

```
socket.on('user_online', function(data){
    document.getElementById("online").innerHTML = "ONLINE USERS (" + data + ")";
});

//Add the online users to the list one by one
chatCount = 0;
socket.on('user-list-append', function(data){
```

will become this

```
socket.on('user_online', function(data){
    document.getElementById("online").innerHTML = "ONLINE USERS (" + data + ")";
});

//Add the online users to the list one by one    chatCount =    socket.on('user-list-append', function(data){
```

They don't automatically  make a new line after the comment since maybe because they don't know where the comments ends.

I could simply replace "//" with "/* ... */", But i'm just curious if there is a better way to solve this problem like maybe they have some options to apply

**Update #1:**

lib: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/tree/master/js/lib

Try put copy paste the code below in http://jsbeautifier.org/ and you can see what I mean.

```
socket.on('user_online', function(data){ document.getElementById("online").innerHTML = "ONLINE USERS (" + data + ")"; }); //Add the online users to the list one by one chatCount = 0; socket.on('user-list-append', function(data){
```

Is there any options to use to let the lib know where to make a new line after "//" comments for the JavaScript that are Word Warped or Minified?

Comment: What js-beautify library are you talking about?

Comment: Have you considered changing that library, if they can't even parse JS correctly?

Comment: I used https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/tree/master/js/lib, the parse is not done by this lib in my case, and there's no problem about it.

Comment: ok my false, the problem is on the parse side, since my function remove all the formatting and wrap it all in one line, therefore the lib really don't know where to stop for the comment.

Comment: So, the problem is not with the beatifier (or its parser), but with your minification. It needs to remove all comments before putting everything in one line (and even then, there might be more things to consider, like ASI).

Answer (score 0):

Your first code block and the one you suggest we copy from to test (the third one), do not contain the same code.  The carriage return is a very important character when interpretting comments that start with '//'.

This isn't really a question about beautify-js. The real question here is how did you create that third block of code? You can't just run all the lines together and expect it to work.

The third block of code is NOT valid javascript. If you had taken the first block of code and used, say uglify-js, on it, it would not have comments in it anymore. There is quite a bit of interpretation that needs to happen to be able to run js altogether on one or a few lines. Other things it would consider would be lines that end only with a carriage return would need to have a semicolon inserted, etc.

What beautify-js did in this particular case is exactly right. Specifically, when '//' is encountered all the rest of the characters **to the end of the line** must be interpretted as a comment. This is exactly what it has done and that is how javascript is supposed to be interpretted.